# Python: modify element in a nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
x = {'a': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 'b': {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}}
```

I want to add an element to a nested dict. Basically i want to get this:

```
x = {'a': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 'b': {3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}}
```

How can i achieve this?

Unfortunately, dict has no .append() method...

Comment: You'd add a new key-value pair in a nested dictionary in the same way as in any other dictionary. `x['b'][5] = 'five'`

Comment: Indeed, now that I reread it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get the dictionary corresponding to the key `'b'`. You can do it with:

```
x['b']
```

This is a dictionary and you can update it normally:

```
x['b'][5] = 'five'
```

Comment: Worked like magic! Thank you guys! =D

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as this `x["b"][5] = "five"`